# dynamic x-axis with fixed start and end points

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to write a line of code that labels my dynamic x-axis at the first point (year) given to a function, at the last point (year) given to a function, and in reasonable ticks (depending on the period) in between. So far I have come up with this:

```
start <- 1851
end <- 2016

plot(c(start, end), c(0, 1), type = "n", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", bty = "n", xlab = "Year", ylab = "")

axis(1, at=c(round(seq(start, end, ((end - start) / (start / (end - start)) * 1.5)), 0), end), label = c(round(seq(start, end, ((end - start) / (start / (end - start)) * 1.5)), 0), end))
```

The trouble make is this pice:

```
c(round(seq(start, end, ((end - start) / (start / (end - start)) * 1.5)), 0), end)

#  [1] 1851 1851 1873 1895 1917 1939 1961 1983 2005 2016
```

the problem is when the second last tick and the last tick (fixed) are fairly close together the axis does not look nice and only the second last tick is labeled, so I tried:

```
c(start, round(seq((start + ((end - start) / (start / (end - start)) * 1.5)), (end - ((end - start) / (start / (end - start)) * 1.5)), ((end - start) / (start / (end - start)) * 1.5)), 0), end)

# [1] 1851 1873 1895 1917 1939 1961 1983 2016
```

this is ought to fix the second tick and the second last tick one ticksize apart from the first and last tick. It works for e.g.

```
start <- 1860
end <- 2010

c(start, round(seq((start + ((end - start) / (start / (end - start)) * 1.5)), (end - ((end - start) / (start / (end - start)) * 1.5)), ((end - start) / (start / (end - start)) * 1.5)), 0), end)

# [1] 1860 1878 1896 1914 1933 1951 1969 1987 2010
```

but breaks apart for short periods

```
start <- 1944
end <- 1966

c(start, round(seq((start + ((end - start) / (start / (end - start)) * 1.5)), (end - ((end - start) / (start / (end - start)) * 1.5)), ((end - start) / (start / (end - start)) * 1.5)), 0), end)

    #  [1] 1944 1944 1945 1945 1945 1946 1946 1947 1947 1947 1948 1948 1948 1949 1949 1950 1950
# [18] 1950 1951 1951 1951 1952 1952 1953 1953 1953 1954 1954 1954 1955 1955 1956 1956 1956
```

# [35] 1957 1957 1957 1958 1958 1959 1959 1959 1960 1960 1960 1961 1961 1962 1962 1962 1963
   # [52] 1963 1963 1964 1964 1965 1965 1965 1966

Any ideas for a pice of code to scale the axis nicely irrespective of the period?